# Just starting, having problems with knees/ankles

Tags: workout, knees

I'm just starting a workout program at 25 years old really for the first time.  I have a bit of a routine going, involving the treadmill, arm and leg presses etc, and the stationary bike.

My problem is that my knees seem to "lock" (feel very stiff) when I get off the bike, and my knees and ankles start to hurt after a few minutes on the treadmill.

Any suggestions on how I can reduce these annoyances?  Do I need to re-arrange my routine?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you need to necessarily re-arrange your routine, but stretching your knees before and during and after your exercise routine will help greatly. You also might want to look into nutrient supplements since you're first starting to exercise and already feeling joint stiffness.

Answer (score 2):

If you've never really exercised before, your connective tissues (tendons and ligaments) could be quite weak.

Start small, with workouts that are short/easy enough not to cause the lockups and pain, and gradually increase your time on the bike and treadmill as your body adapts to the new load.

If there is absolutely no amount of time on the bike/treadmill that will work for this, you may want to see a doctor.